# GADT and proof of equality

Tags: haskell, types, gadt

I want to hide some type information in a GADT, here forgetting about the `key` type

```
data Query  where
   Query :: Ord key =>  Map.Map key String  -> Query

 one ::  Ord key => key -> Query
 one  k =
   let m = Map.insert k "hello" Map.empty
   in Query m
```

How can I pass on some equality constraint to use it elsewhere as in :

```
other :: Ord key => key -> Query -> Maybe String
other k (Query ad) =  Map.lookup k ad
```

Comment: It's kinda the point of hiding type information that you _can't_ do this, isn't it?

Comment: absolutely. but not forgetting = forgetting + having a proof of type equality. and that's what I would like to do to not carry all those parameters around. as a client, other should never be allowed to see what type it is. but I write it also as an implementor, hence I want to keep the proof

Comment: Could you give an example of a full scenario in which you intend to do this?

Comment: I have a bunch of code using a type. I want to add a type variable which does not concern other libraries. I am the only one who instatiate this type so I know it is safe. When I explicitly forget about that type variable so that other code does not have to be polluted with my type which they should treat abstractly, I would like to have a proof of what I forgot that I can still use that extra type variable which I have just added.

Comment: I agree its totally wrong though... was just wondering if there was a way to cheat ...

Comment: If you just keep the type variable visible – but universally-quantified – then everybody else has to treat it abstractly too, but it's still there for when you want to access it and apply whatever constraints you have floating around. — If you actually have a global proof that _all `key`s have the same type_, then you should not make it a variable at all. If you have only two or three such types (and don't plan to allow many more), you shouldn't use a type variable either, but a variant type which has discrete options for the different instantiations.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: your comment makes for a very appropriate answer.

Comment: Figured I wanted to have <> part of the system know that some existentials were the same. "In general, we need to open an existential datatype with a scope that covers all terms that need to share a particular implementation type. This enforces an strict block structure on the program, and prevents us from defining these terms in separate compilation units for
example. This is one of the most important reasons that existential
types are generally dismissed as the basis for abstract types in
module systems" http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/daan/download/papers/existentials.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

– leftaroundabout Jan 6 at 17:19

If you just keep the type variable visible – but universally-quantified – then everybody else has to treat it abstractly too, but it's still there for when you want to access it and apply whatever constraints you have floating around. — If you actually have a global proof that all keys have the same type, then you should not make it a variable at all. If you have only two or three such types (and don't plan to allow many more), you shouldn't use a type variable either, but a variant type which has discrete options for the different instantiations.